# Ionic grid trouble

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, flexbox, row, ion-grid

```
<ion-grid>

  <ion-row wrap style="background-color: #25dfc3">
    <ion-col>
      <ion-slides pager>
          <ion-slide>
            <h1>Slide 1</h1>
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
            <h1>Slide 2</h1>
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
            <h1>Slide 3</h1>
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
            <h1>Slide 4</h1>
            </ion-slide>
        </ion-slides>
      </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-row style="background-color: #ffffff;">
    <ion-col>Amethyst!</ion-col>
  </ion-row>

</ion-grid>
```

Is there any way to make my first row bigger than the second? I've been watching many tutorials but it seems that the flexbox solutions doesn't help me.

Comment: bigger meaning increase height?

Comment: You need to provide a working code snippet that reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can just add a height in the first row.

```
<ion-grid>

    <ion-row wrap style="background-color: #25dfc3; height: 300px;">
        <ion-col>
            <ion-slides pager>
                <ion-slide>
                    <h1>Slide 1</h1>
                </ion-slide>
                <ion-slide>
                    <h1>Slide 2</h1>
                </ion-slide>
                <ion-slide>
                    <h1>Slide 3</h1>
                </ion-slide>
                <ion-slide>
                    <h1>Slide 4</h1>
                </ion-slide>
            </ion-slides>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row style="background-color: #ffffff;">
        <ion-col>Amethyst!</ion-col>
    </ion-row>

</ion-grid>
```

View it here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-rhdvzq

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the issue with flex like so:

```
<ion-grid>

  <ion-row class="top">
    <ion-col>
      <ion-slides pager>
          <ion-slide>
            <div class="sprite">

            </div>
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
            <h1>Slide 2</h1>
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
            <h1>Slide 3</h1>
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
            <h1>Slide 4</h1>
            </ion-slide>
        </ion-slides>
      </ion-col>
  </ion-row>


  <ion-row style="background-color: #ffffff;">
    <ion-col col-1></ion-col>
    <ion-col col-10>
        <button ion-button block (click)="login()"  >Inicia sesión con Facebook</button>
        <p></p>
        <button ion-button block  color="secondary" (click)="pushPage()" >Accesa con tu teléfono</button>
        <p></p>
        <a href="#">Términos y condiciones</a>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-1></ion-col>
  </ion-row>

</ion-grid>
```

```
login-tutorial{
.top {
    flex: 4;
    background-color: #e8343b;
}

.button-block{
    margin-top: 14px;
}

a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .7em;

    float: left;
    margin-left: 30%;
    margin-top: 18%;

}

h1  {
    color: #fbb034;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
    background: #fbb034;
    opacity: 1;
}

.sprite {
    width: 47.25px;
    height: 51px;

    /*margin-left: 42%;*/
    margin: auto;
    background-image: url("../../assets/imgs/babyL.png");

    animation: luigui 1s steps(11, end) infinite;
}

@keyframes luigui {
    from {
        background-position: 0px;
    }
    to{
        background-position: -549.25px;
    }
}
}
```

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0OrL.png)

Then I copied the same code to another app, however, the result is different. It seem like the flex is not working...

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFE7A.png)